# Clarify doubts about polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

In my math algebra class my teacher says

> If $$(1+n)^3=A+Bn+Cn(n-1)+Dn(n-1)(n-2)$$
>   then find $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$.

I know how to solve it.
But I don't understand what it really mean and why he says both LHS and RHS are equal. Please someone explain me how it is true.

Also tell me what is $n^3$ by using same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you interpret the equal sign as meaning equal for some $n$ or equal for all $n$.  If equal for all $n$ then you mean "equal as polynomials in $n$".  The meat of the calculation is that such an equation cannot be true for all $n$ unless the coefficients of the different powers of $n$ are equal.  That fact basically comes down to the fact that a polynomial can only have finitely many zeros.  Think about what happens if two polynomials are equal no matter what $n$ you substitute in, but the two sides have different coefficients.  Then you can substract all terms to one side and get a non-zero polynomial that has infinitely many zeros which is impossible.  Now if you want to prove that a polynomial has only finitely many zeros you have to work a bit harder because it's not completely trivial.

Comment: I won't write as maths I just write as math .the error is due to autocorrect option in my tablet .sorry for that

Comment: @SathasivamK That's good, I edited that comment out of my post.  Did you understand the rest of what I wrote?

Comment: Assume n$\in$N,then this equation is correct ?sir,and my teacher says you can put n=0,n=1,n=2&equating co efficient of $n^3$ to find A,B,C&D.

Comment: That's right, because we want to find $A,B,C,D$ so that the equation holds for all $n$.  The reason this works boils down to the fact that a polynomial can only have finitely many zeros.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing u again sir, does zero of polynomial is same as root of polynomial ? Also can u briefly explain "Think about what happens if two polynomials are equal no matter what nn you substitute in, but the two sides have different coefficients. Then you can substract all terms to one side and get a non-zero polynomial that has infinitely many zeros which is impossible."

Comment: Yes zero means root.  What if $An+B=Cn+D$ but it's not true that $A=C$ and $B=D$?  Then $(A-C)n+(B-D)=0$ which means you have found a non-zero polynomial with infinitely many roots.  Infinitely many because it's true *for all* $n$.  That's impossible, so no such equation can exist unless we have $A=C$ and $B=D$.

Comment: Thank you a lot sir .I want to clarify some more doubt, can I ask u  again when I feel difficulty sir?

Comment: No problem, you can always ask if I don't answer it's only because I didn't have time in that moment.